# Simulate XMLHttpRequest as from localhost or Remote Connection to a machine

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, remote-desktop

I have a website hosted in ISS (can be other) that loads when it's called on localhost but not from extern :) like: http://:8081/Website.html.

The verification whether the website is called from localhost it's on the client in a js script that I can’t modify as it’s encrypted.

So I was thinking at two options:

1. Develop an ASP application that has a remote desktop connection to the machine that host the website (not some many example on how to).
2. Maybe configure the IIS configuration (didn't found how)
3. I'm out of ideas

Do you have any other solution or can you point on how can I do one of the above?

I have tried the WinForm solution from here: https://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/remotedesktop_csharpnet.aspx and it doesn't work. And I prefer a website.

Updates:

The only working solution that I have for now is to configure a Remote Desktop Services (Web Access) as I hosted the application on Server 2008 R2. Then I only shared the browser that has the localhost page as default page

The javascript files are all minified and encrypted, meaning that if I search localhost as a word in all the files, nothing shows up. So fixing the client will be hard.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall..? Did you try open the web from another computer in the same network?

Comment: What does the URL that the client sends look like? If it is an FQDN that you do not control, then you are out of options here except to change it in the client app. If you control the domain, then you can either configure bindings in IIS as explained [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrad/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools/) or (if that cannot be done) create an ASP.NET app that serves as sort of a proxy i.e. make a request to the host machine and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create a new Site Binding on IIS and access the site using the binding hostname? This requires your network DNS to register the hostname to the IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are dealing with encrypted(???) javascript that is hardcoded to display DOM only if it is loaded from localhost.

If by encrypted you mean minified you should still be able to find reference to "localhost" and modify javascript in minified version. If it is really encrypted by a wrapper of third party javascript library then I would suggest you to rewrite javascript. I mean how can there be any quality code in javascript code that is hardcoded to load only from localhost?

Fix the client and stop exploring other solutions like remote desktop connection. None of them are practical and sustainable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use WebRTC, but it's supported for Chrome and Firefox. It allows two users to communicate directly, browser to browser using the RTCPeerConnection API.